# KeyError 'django' occured after adding "rest_framework" to settings.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a django project and trying to use rest_framework. I'm running the project through docker desktop engine. Everything is fine until I add "rest_framework" to my project's settings.py in INSTALLED_APPS. I'm getting errors as below:

```
2023-07-28 15:08:59 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
2023-07-28 15:08:59     return self._engines[alias]
2023-07-28 15:08:59            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59 KeyError: 'django'
2023-07-28 15:08:59 
2023-07-28 15:08:59 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-07-28 15:08:59 
2023-07-28 15:08:59 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/code/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
2023-07-28 15:08:59     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
2023-07-28 15:08:59     utility.execute()
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
2023-07-28 15:08:59     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
2023-07-28 15:08:59     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
2023-07-28 15:08:59     super().execute(*args, **options)
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
2023-07-28 15:08:59     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
2023-07-28 15:08:59              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 96, in handle
2023-07-28 15:08:59     self.run(**options)
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 103, in run
2023-07-28 15:08:59     autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 637, in run_with_reloader
2023-07-28 15:08:59     start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 622, in start_django
2023-07-28 15:08:59     reloader.run(django_main_thread)
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 327, in run
2023-07-28 15:08:59     autoreload_started.send(sender=self)
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
2023-07-28 15:08:59     return [
2023-07-28 15:08:59            ^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
2023-07-28 15:08:59     (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
2023-07-28 15:08:59                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 41, in watch_for_template_changes
2023-07-28 15:08:59     for directory in get_template_directories():
2023-07-28 15:08:59                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 14, in get_template_directories
2023-07-28 15:08:59     for backend in engines.all():
2023-07-28 15:08:59                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
2023-07-28 15:08:59     return [self[alias] for alias in self]
2023-07-28 15:08:59            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
2023-07-28 15:08:59     return [self[alias] for alias in self]
2023-07-28 15:08:59             ~~~~^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
2023-07-28 15:08:59     engine = engine_cls(params)
2023-07-28 15:08:59              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
2023-07-28 15:08:59     options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
2023-07-28 15:08:59                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
2023-07-28 15:08:59     libraries = get_installed_libraries()
2023-07-28 15:08:59                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
2023-07-28 15:08:59     for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
2023-07-28 15:08:59     module = import_module(entry[1])
2023-07-28 15:08:59              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2023-07-28 15:08:59     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-07-28 15:08:59            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 11, in <module>
2023-07-28 15:08:59     from rest_framework.compat import apply_markdown, pygments_highlight
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/compat.py", line 26, in <module>
2023-07-28 15:08:59     from django.contrib.postgres import fields as postgres_fields
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/fields/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
2023-07-28 15:08:59     from .array import *  # NOQA
2023-07-28 15:08:59     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/fields/array.py", line 3, in <module>
2023-07-28 15:08:59     from django.contrib.postgres import lookups
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/lookups.py", line 4, in <module>
2023-07-28 15:08:59     from .search import SearchVector, SearchVectorExact, SearchVectorField
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/search.py", line 1, in <module>
2023-07-28 15:08:59     import psycopg2
2023-07-28 15:08:59   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
2023-07-28 15:08:59     from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
2023-07-28 15:08:59 SystemError: initialization of _psycopg raised unreported exception
```

As for versions, I'm using djangorestframework==3.14.0, django==3.2, python==3.11

I've tried to degrade my djangorestframework version but it didn't work.